# Is this a bug with editing posts?

Tags: support, bug, editing

I just answered a [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/667040/305718) and edited it within a short period. But this is what I saw:

[image]

What happened to the grace period of 5 minutes for editing a post?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The comment broke the grace period.**

According to [ex-CM Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251876/241919),

> Edits will be rolled into the previous revision if the previous revision was created by the same author and *none* of the following conditions are present:
>
> - The previous revision was created 5 minutes or more in the past
> - **A comment has been added to the post after the previous revision by anyone *other than* the editor**
> - An answer has been added to the post after the previous revision (even if the answer was posted by the editor)
> - The previous revision was a rollback
> - The new revision is a rollback
> - [[as of April 3rd, 2017](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341105/closure-should-end-the-grace-period-for-edits)] The question was closed after the previous revision.

<sup>(Emphasis added)</sup>

According to [the post's timeline](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/667040/timeline):

- 2021-09-20 10:19:55Z: answer posted
- **2021-09-20 10:21:12Z: OP commented; breaking the grace period**
- 2021-09-20 10:22:52Z: answer edited; new revision was created due to above